# Italian word lists

Tags: resources

Does anyone know where I might be able to find a list of 5000-20000 common Italian words with translations ? I learn to read languages very efficiently by cramming vocabulary but I can't find such resources (beyond dictionaries).

Comment: Welcome to Italian SE! "A list of 5000-20000 most common words with translation" is a dictionary, simply by definition. Nobody could possibly provide it in any other format. You might find useful our [reference list](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online), if you need something beyond dictionaries.

Comment: Well, can you point me to such a small dictionary ? My pocket dictionary is 75,000 words. For other languages I have learned I have had such resources available e.g. in Latin http://www.the-orb.net/latwords.html

Comment: You can start with something like [A short Italian dictionary](https://archive.org/details/shortitaliandict01hoaruoft) in two volumes (IT-EN and EN-IT). Just beware of the year of publication and don't expect to find words like "computer" in there. And then Amazon offers plenty of abridged/pocket vocabularies; try to look at [5000 words compilation](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Italian-Vocabulary-Thematic-Approach/dp/0764123955) and go through the "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" list to find something to your taste.

Comment: I can't buy books, I really need a free online list.

Comment: "A short Italian dictionary" is free; you can read it online or download as a pdf, epub, or txt file. For anything else, I'm afraid to ask, have you tried googling "most common Italian words"? Later you can always come to Italian SE, if you encounter a specific or unexplainable issue.